# Populate modal with firebase data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase

I create a modal to save data to DB, but now I'm trying to open a modal with the current values that are already saved to edit them. But I have no success

Here the edit modal (modifyed from the previews modal):

```
<!-- edit Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modifique o incidente</h4>

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Local</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="localEdit" placeholder="Onde aconteceu?">
                </div>
               
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descricao</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="descricaoEdit" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Link da Imagem</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imgLinkEdit" placeholder="Tem imagem?">
                  </div>


                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="updateCard(event)">Adicionar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
              </form>

        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Heres the way on javascript that im creating the cards to the front:

```
               const content = `
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img class="card-img-top data-imgLink" data-src="${doc.data().foto}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text" id="data-local">Local: ${doc.data().local}</p>
                          <p class="card-text data-description">Descricao: ${doc.data().descricao}</p>
                          <p class="card-text data-situation">Situacao: ${doc.data().situacao}</p>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary edit-button" id="editButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" onclick="deleteCard('${doc.id}')">Apagar</button>
                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                       
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
```

And heres the function that i tryed to create to pass the values to the edit modal
(i'm trying only with the first input tho):

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-button", function(){

    var local = $(this).find('#data-local').text();
    $('#localEdit').parent().val(local);

    console.log("clicado");
});
```

As you can see, im passing the right html id to the function.

Any clue of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error, `$('#localEdit')` will search for element with id **localEdit**, which is an input field and `.val()` works with an input field. So, instead of `$('#localEdit').parent().val(local);` you can write it as `$('#localEdit').val(local);`

So in this case you've an id referring to localEdit which is an input field and `.val()` function will work with it, no need to call `.parent()`.

Comment: no success yet. Debugging in console i can se that the ```var local = $(this).find('#data-local').text(); ```is returning empty. So idk why

Comment: So instead of $('#localEdit').val("Some Value"); 
if this works, which means var local has no value then.